# How to Set 'User assignment required' with Az powershell for an Azure enterprise Application

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I would like your opinion on the following:

- i am able to update parameter *User assignment required* via Azure Portal
- i am able to update parameter *User assignment required* via Powershell using module AzureAD and cmdlet Set-AzureADServicePrincipal
- I would like to update parameter *User assignment required* via Powershell using module Az (and not AzureAD)

[image]
Do you know if it exist an equivalent which look like Set-AzADServicePrincipal and works like Set-AzureADServicePrincipal ? I tried Update-AzADServicePrincipal but there is no way to update this field.

By the way, what is the mindset behind module AzureAD which have cmdlt to manage AzureADApp versus module Az which have also cmdlet to manage also AzureADApp (with limitation) ? Thx for your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the command `Update-AzADServicePrincipal` is not supported to set the `User assignment required`.

In your scenario, not sure why you don't want to use `AzureAD` module, if you just could use `Az` module, you can use my workaround below.

**Note:** Please make sure your `Az` module is latest, if not, please update the module with `Update-Module -Name Az` in the powershell session ran as admin, because the `Get-AzAccessToken` used below is a new command. Also make sure your logged user account/service principal has the permission to update the service principals in your tenant, if you are using service principal to login, you need the *Application permission*(not *Delegated permission*) `Application.ReadWrite.All` of `Microsoft Graph` in the `API permissions` of the AD App.

[image]

The use the commands below, `Invoke-RestMethod` is included by powershell by default, so don't worry about it, the commands get the token for MS Graph and call the MS Graph API directly.

```
$token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl https://graph.microsoft.com).Token
$headers = @{
    'Authorization'="Bearer $token"
    'Content-type'="application/json"
}
$body = @{
    appRoleAssignmentRequired = "true"
} | ConvertTo-Json
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Patch -Uri https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/<object-id of the service principal> -Headers $headers -Body $body
```

After running the commands, there is no output, check the result in the portal, it works fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the time you take to provide your workaround Joy Wang and it helps me a lot. To answer your question I do not want to use module AzureAD if all command can be done by module Az . May i ask you a last favor ? Do you know if a workaround exist for the 3 following command : Get-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment / New-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment / Set-AzureADApplication ?

Comment: @terry Yes, you can, just call the correspond MS Graph like the format above,  [Get-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http),  [New-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http),  [Set-AzureADApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Comment: Hi Joy wang. I tried to use same format you described but I cannot get what i need :( To avoid to have a too long thread i will open a new one. Hope you can jump on it

Answer (score 0):

The command you are using is not supported as you can see the below error screenshot please refer the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/update-azadserviceprincipal?view=azps-5.1.0) for query and its parameter

[image]

To consider this feature request for the future, you can raise the [user's voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) so that  the product group can prioritize this feature

There is another way you can update this parameter please refer to this [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/45211#issuecomment-569034398)